# iPhone video gets displayed in lower right hand corner when orated from vertical to horizontal

Tags: iphone

When my app runs, the video and the phone is rated to landscape mode, my video then plays in the lower right hand corner, is there a way to have the video be in the middle of the screen when the user rotate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're running your video, but try doing it like this (after importing MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h):

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"ExampleVideo" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
MPMoviePlayerController *testMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
testMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
[testMovie play];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
```

I call that when I play movies and it works fine with rotations.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your input.  I'm a little confuse it seems like you are creating 2 movie controllers? TestMovie and moviePlayer?

Comment: As described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056844/mpmovieplayercontroller-vs-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller "The MPMoviePlayerController is just a movie player, it provides a way for you to play movies on the iPhone, a MPMoviePlayerViewController is an actual view controller subclass that takes care of presentation of the MPMoviePlayerController"

Comment: Essentially, the Player controllers the playback and the PlayerView provides a presentation for it in a full-screen viewer.