# MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

My code plays the video properly but not in full screen.

```
-----------  
|_______  |  
|XXXXXXX| |  
|XXXXXXX| |    
-----------
```

Its size is about the size of the X filed area.
I am running this on an ipad2.

```
 NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie.mp4" ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
    videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:videoPlayer];
    [self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
    [videoPlayer setFullscreen:YES];
    videoPlayer.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];  
    [videoPlayer play];    
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

Comment: Apparently if you add it to your viewControllers `self.view` it shows as you mentioned. I've fixed it by adding your player to a a temporary `UIView`. But it's not a complete answer.

Comment: check the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056844/mpmovieplayercontroller-vs-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller/5834370#5834370 it may help you

Comment: I know its not the best answer... 
But it works :) cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the frame of your `MPMoviePlayerController` to 1024x768.

```
videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768); //748 if you have status bar.
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.
*edit: Try this way, it's the one I use.

```
UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
[self.view addSubview:tempView];

playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.orangebob.com/files/movie.mp4"]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:[playerViewController moviePlayer]];

playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
[tempView addSubview:playerViewController.view]; //This *fixes* it, but it's kinda dirty.



MPMoviePlayerController *player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];

[player play];
```

Comment: Still have the same problem :(

Comment: Did you remove this line? `videoPlayer.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];`

Comment: Yes... I uploaded the video to www.orangebob.com/files/movie.mp4 if that will help you...

Comment: Updated my answer, hope that's more helpful.

Comment: your code works :) but still isn't fullscreen:(
I now have a white bar on the bottom.. about 1024x300.

Comment: Are you in landscape or portrait? By your drawing I just assumed you were in landscape :(