# How to display ToolBar Buttons on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to display `UIToolBar` with `BarButtonItems on MPMoviePlayerController`. Not sure how will I implement it.

I am trying to play the video file when user taps on one of the cell of UITableView. At that time I would like to give an option to user to share the video on FB or tweeter.

Not sure how will I display the **share BarButtonItem on MPMoviePlayerController**. I am trying to implement something similar to the photo app that comes with iPhone.

Can anyone please help me out?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure want to use MPMoviePlayerController instead of MPMoviePlayerViewController? This answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/5834370/503527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPMovieplayer is not the right choice for this purpose. You can create a custom movie player with AVPlayer(found under AVFoundation.framework) that would serve your purpose. Create any normal ViewController in your project and add an AVPlayer with code something like below:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
//prepare player
self.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:<# NSURL for the video file #>];
self.videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause;

//prepare player layer
self.videoPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.videoPlayer];
self.videoPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
self.videoPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.videoPlayerLayer];

//add player item status notofication handler
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"videoPlayer.currentItem.status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

//notification handler when player item completes playback
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.videoPlayer.currentItem];
}

//called when playback completes
-(void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
[self.videoPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero]; //rewind at the end of play

 //other tasks
 }

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"videoPlayer.currentItem.status"]) {
    //NSLog(@"player status changed");

    if (self.videoPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
        //player is ready to play and you can enable your playback buttons here
    }
}
}
```

As this would be normal view controller, you can add a toolbar buttons/buttons to it, for playing/sharing, etc. and trigger the player actions and any other related action like below:

```
-(IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    [self.videoPlayer play];
}
-(IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
    [self.videoPlayer pause];
}
//etc.
```

Also make sure to remove the observers in your dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    //remove observers
    @try {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"videoPlayer.currentItem.status" context:NULL];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {}
    @try {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.videoPlayer.currentItem];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {}

    //other deallocations
    [super dealloc];
}
```

More detailed and sophisticated explanation of the process can be found under apples companion guide, available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW1)

Comment: Works like charm except app crashes after few seconds with log. An instance of class MoviePlayerViewController was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0xd55e030> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0xd55e120: Observer: 0xd5562e0, Key path: videoPlayer.currentItem.status, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0xd55df70>
)

Comment: Make sure to remove the observers in your dealloc. I forgot to mention that. Please see my edits.