# MPMoviePlayers seem to point to the same single instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am creating as a fun project a few players in `UITableView` cells.

ex:

```
self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.player prepareToPlay];
[self.player play];
```

The above is created in a table view cell subclass and then added to the `contentView`. Nothing fancy and no custom overlay, every default.

They show. And for testing purposes I am using the same url for every players.

It plays, but the problem occurs because I think that every single player is of the same object.

By that I mean, when I start playing one in one cell, I can see that the other (random) plays as well. And if I start and then stop in one player, I can resume the playing by clicking on another player in another cell.

I don't see where the problem comes from because I am initializing the players in every table view cell subclass (i.e., each cell should have their own player).

So, other than that I am forced to assume that - if every player opens the same url, does the API under the hood apply some "magic" that it would not allocate more players and every one points to the same one (instance), even when we are actually alloc and initializing more than one player?

This really beats me.

---

Cell subclass (I am only testing the player, so there are no other custom labels, views or the sort. Just the player):

```
//Here in initWithStyle, after alloc and initializing the player 
//.....

self.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

[self.contentView addSubview:self.player.view]; 

//player is declared as a property with `strong and nonatomic`

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                  selector:@selector(finished:)                                              
                                  name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification
                                  object:nil];
[self.player prepareToPlay];

//End initWithStyle
```

And in:

```
- (void)finished:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"finished"); 
   //This gets called multiple times endlessly even with 1 cell 
   //and without scrolling. But when added on UIView the notification 
   //will only be called once on the UIView class.
}
```

Comment: Where and when are they added to the content view?  In what method?  And if not `init`, what calls the method and when?

Comment: Is it two cells on screen at the same time playing together, or do you have to scroll?

Comment: May be the "random cell" in which you could resume the same video is reused cell. Try to clear the state of the player in `prepareForReuse`

Comment: @vhristoskov That's sort of what I'm thinking, but a cell and the cell it was reused from can never be on the screen at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps include the relevant code from the cell subclass?

Comment: **Don't** put a *model* object (`MPMoviePlayerController`) in a *view* (`UITableViewCell`). Absolutely don't. Please follow the MVC paradigm while coding for Cocoa/Cocoa Touch.

Comment: You are getting it wrong. `MPMoviewPlayerController` is a *model* object, something which has no place in a *view*.

Comment: @duci9y Would you happen to have supporting evidence to your claim??? Please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056844/mpmovieplayercontroller-vs-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller).

Comment: @Unheilig Your own source claims that its `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, which is the view controller. `MPMoviePlayerController` is a model object. Either way, a view has no business owning a model *or* a controller.

Comment: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%201_1.pdf would be a good starting resource. You'd have to redesign your app from scratch.

Comment: And I still think that `MPMoviePlayerController` is _meant_ and _designed_ to be incorporated in a view hierarchy (i.e., added as subview) while `MPMoviePlayerViewController` is a controller that handle controller responsibilities and has a `MPMoviePlayerController` as its property, which provides the view responsibilities.

Comment: I think you should learn a bit more about the basics of Cocoa programming and then go into advanced frameworks like this.

Comment: @duci9y I have to disagree with you on what you have claimed so far. In addition, `MPMoviePlayerController` is _in_ the Cocoa Touch framework and it is definitely not more advanced than `AVAudioPlayer`.